# Array of objects to reduce based on values

Tags: javascript, lodash

Algorithms are not my strong point and I've hit an issue thats causing my brain to implode.

I have an array of object, for example:

```
const objects = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "date": new Date()
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 1,
    "date": new Date()
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "date": new Date()
  }, 
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
    "date": new Date()
  },
  {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    "date": new Date()
  }
];
```

These are messages where 'a' is the sender and 'b' is the receiver.
I want to group these messages into 'conversations' (for the want of a better term)

so a message from 'a' to 'b' is the same 'conversation' as a message from 'b' to 'a'.

I have tried using loop within loops within loops to filter these but I end up with spaghetti
I then try'd looking and creating temporary objects to store them and do it that way, but that also lead to excessive loops.

I feel like there is a better way to do this with a `reduce`? maybe

Any help into this would be very much appreciated.
(my code attempt where many, many lines or junk so haven't posted so save peoples eyes)

N.b. I have added the lodash tag as I feel there are lodash methods for this problem, but I couldn't find one, but still feel there is something in there that would be useful

Comment: why is there no reference on the messages, and what are the identical dates for?

Comment: just to make the code shorter and easier to read, but you are right the date in reality is a timestamp from the server and there are more fields on the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange the objects into an object indexed by `a_b`, with the smaller number first - for example, a message with `a 1` and `b 2` would get the key `1_2`. A message with `a 2` and `b 1` would get the same key.

```js
const objects = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "content": 'msg1'
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 1,
    "content": 'msg2'
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "content": 'msg3'
  }, 
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
    "content": 'msg4'
  },
  {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    "content": 'msg5'
  }
];

const conversations = {};
for (const obj of objects) {
  const key = [obj.a, obj.b].sort((a, b) => a - b).join('_');
  if (!conversations[key]) conversations[key] = [];
  conversations[key].push(obj);
}
console.log(conversations);
```

Comment: You should group the message-objects, not just the content, since it's not guaranteed that a conversation will have alternating messages started by the one with the lower id. And `const key = [a, b].sort();` would be sufficient here, although I'm sure it will trigger everyones OCD.

Comment: `.sort()` will sort lexiographically, not numerically; eg, it'll give `1 11 2`. While that *works* since making pairs is all that mattes, it's more confusing than useful IMO

Comment: ah thats fantastic. i was trying a similar thing with adding a key to a new object but I was using about 6 times as much code. amazing work, thanks greatly